# ECMAscript:can v8 in chrome support?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, v8

I learned that v8 support ecma262 version3, but all explorer show that they support emcascript5, is that true,can v8 in chrome support ecmascript5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome's V8 supports ECMA-262 (ecmascript) Version 5.  See https://code.google.com/p/v8/

Comment: @shangxinbo Could you *accept* the answer if it solved your issue? (the mark under the score of the answer)